# Calculate normal of a single triangle in 3D space

Tags: 3d, geometry

I am in a graphics programming class and I am doing the written homework, not programming, so I hope this is appropriate for this site.  I have this problem:

> Compute the unit normal for the triangles specified by each of the
>   following vertex sets (assume the triangles are facing away from the
>   origin):

I took linear algebra over a year ago, my teacher then said that he wouldn't teach cross products because only the Computer Science people in the class would need it and it would be covered when they needed it (it wasn't because they assumed the linear algebra teacher did it), and I have checked two dozen explanations and they are all way over my head.

This problem has three different problems within it, so if someone could walk me through how to solve a single one that didn't involve tons of variables and Greek letters it would be greatly appreciated.

Part A of this problem has these three coordinates as the points of the triangle: `[1, 1, 1]; [1, -1, 1]; [1, 0, -1]`.  I tried cobbling together different formulas and explanations and I got that the normal vector is [4, 0, 0], but that doesn't seem right since I know enough to know that this triangle doesn't lie on the y-z plane.  The only other thing I have is the formula:

```
(A x B) / | A x B |
```

I know that A and B are two random sides of the triangle represented as a vector, and calculated by subtracting V2 and V1 for A and V3 and V1 for B, but I don't understand what exactly it is telling me to do.

Comment: WTF?! Didn't teach cross products? They're useful outside of Computer Science... in fact, I never once used them in any CS curriculum, only in specialized applications of CS. Engineers, physicists, etc... all use the cross product frequently, CS students never use them focusing almost entirely on discrete math. Rant aside, a useful property of triangles is that all of their points are guaranteed to lie in a single plane (coplanar), the cross-product between two edges will give you a perpendicular vector (normal). But you usually want to go one step further, and make the normal unit length.

Comment: Note that the cross product is an order-dependent operation. This leads to the discussion of winding order, if you reverse the order of the two cross product operands you will get a normal that faces the other direction. Having studied linear algebra, you should look into the determinant form of the cross product, it will probably make the most sense.

Comment: Stumbled upon this now, and just wanted to comment that the triangle does in fact lie on the y-z plane, and its normal would be any x value [x, 0, 0]. Just thought it was funny.

Answer (score 29):

Quoting from https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Calculating_a_Surface_Normal

> A surface normal for a triangle can be calculated by taking the vector cross product of two edges of that triangle. The order of the vertices used in the calculation will affect the direction of the normal (in or out of the face w.r.t. winding).

So for a triangle `p1, p2, p3`, if the vector `A = p2 - p1` and the vector `B = p3 - p1` then the normal `N = A x B` and can be calculated by:

```
Nx = Ay * Bz - Az * By
Ny = Az * Bx - Ax * Bz
Nz = Ax * By - Ay * Bx
```

Comment: Uy is the 2nd element in U?

Comment: @JuneWang yes. I'll change the letters to avoid the confusion with UV coords

Comment: Hi. I am having 2 issues with this formula. a) orthogonal triangles return zero length normal. b) some triangles also return zero length normal. e.g. p1(3.9585345,12.684328,1.2042775) p2(3.1372554,12.51845,-0.089832544), p3(2.726616,12.435511,-0.7368876). Makes sense to you?  :S

Comment: About my last comment. I still have issues with orthogonal triangles. The 2nd issue I had was not using high precision floats :)

Comment: @AndrésOviedo such triangle is degenerate - all of its points are on the line, it has no surface area and no face direction.