# How to calculate the normals of a box?

Tags: algorithm, graphics

I am trying to create an algorithm that calculate the normals of a model/ mesh. People have been telling me to use the cross products between the two vectors which at first seem like a good idea until I discovered that it might not always work. For instance just imagine a box with its front face sitting at the origin and its back face down the Z axis. Here is an image:

[image]

I do apologize for bad hand writing but that shouldn't be of any significance. As you can see,I cross v and u to get the normal pointing toward the positive z axis. However, If I use that same calculation to calculate the normal for the back face then obviously the normal will then be a vector directing inside the shape. The result is that I have inaccurate normals to calculate the brightness of a light. I want the normal to be facing away from the model at all time.

I know there gotta be a better way to calculate the normal but I don't know what it is. Can anyone suggests to me another algorithm to calculate the normal that would get rid of this problem? If not then there has to be a way to check whether or not a normal is facing inside the object / model. If so then can you suggests it in the answer and where I would find an explanation about it because I would love to have an intuition on how these methodologies work.

Comment: A cross product will always be directional. Remember your right hand rule. If `u x v` gives you a vector pointing in an unexpected direction, then `v x u` will give you a vector of the same magnitude but in the opposite direction.

Comment: The cross product is directional and it seems like you're just getting the right vector in the wrong direction. Perhaps this is just an issue with the order in which you're storing the points representing the faces?

Comment: yah the issue does indeed happens with storing my face in the wrong order but I don't know how to detect that if it is behind a plane then store the order differently. I think that is the whole problem to begin with. Is there any suggestion on how I would detects that since this point is behind another plane then perhaps we just invert the cross product?

Comment: I was under the impression that perhaps there are other methods of calculating the normal that will then know that to invert the normal if it is facing toward the model.

Comment: It is a strange problem, the first thing that comes to my mind is to encapsulate the object using a circle and check which normal( front and back of the face) would intersect with it first. However this will not work for complex shapes. For them I will try to import them to 3DMax or Blender.

Comment: Seems that your vectors are wrong, U should be V1-V2 and V=V3-V2 so that VxU will point in the z direction. Beware that ordering of vertex is important. This may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350792/calculate-normal-of-a-single-triangle-in-3d-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most software packages obey a configurable *cyclic ordering* for triangle indices - clockwise or anti-clockwise. Thus all meshes they export have self-consistent ordering, and as long as your program uses the same convention, you should have nothing to worry about.

---

Having said that, I imagine you want to know what to do in the hypothetical (?) situation where the index ordering is inconsistent.

One method we could use is *ray-intersection*. The important theorem is that *a ray with its source outside the mesh will only intersect the mesh an even number of times, and if inside, odd.*

To do this, we can do the following:

- Calculate the "normal" using the cross product as above (and normalize it) =>  `N`
- Take any point on the triangle (preferably the midpoint)
- Increment this point along the normal by some small *epsilon* value (depends on your floating point format and size of model - I'd say `1e-4` for single and `1e-8` for double precision) => `P`
- Intersect this ray `[dir = N, src = P]` with *all* triangles in the mesh (a good algorithm for this would be [Möller–Trumbore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm))
- If the number of intersections is even, then the ray started from outside of the mesh; this means that the normal points *outwards* from the mesh (because you incremented its source from a point on the surface). - and of course, vice versa.

---

*Minor (-ish ?) digression*: a naive approach to the above, of looping through all triangles in the mesh, would be `O(n)` - and hence the whole procedure would have *quadratic time complexity*. This is perfectly fine for *very* small meshes of ~20 triangles (e.g. a box), but not ideal for any larger!

You can use spatial sub-division techniques to lower the cost of this intersection step:

- *K-D trees / Octrees*: These require `O(n log n)` (for the best algorithm, that is - see [*Ingo Wald*'s paper](http://www.sci.utah.edu/~wald/Publications/2006/NlogN/kdtree.pdf)) to construct, but intersections are guaranteed to be `O(log n)` if done properly. The overall complexity would then be `O(n log n)`, which is pretty much the best you can get
- *Grid*: This simply partitions the search space and triangles into smaller boxes. Construction is `O(n)` and much more memory-efficient. Intersection time is still `O(n)`, but the constant factor is *much* smaller than that of the naive approach.

Answer (score 0):

Cross products are not commutative so `v x u` is not the same as `u x v`. In fact, they will be the exact opposite.

For the front face, you want to take `u x v` (assuming you're in a r[ight-hand coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule)), and the back face you want to cross `v x u`.

See [right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) for more info on how crossing vectors works.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer but that is definitely not the problem I am having. I do know that the cross product is not commutative and I know that I could solve the problem by inverting the cross product for the back. However that is not my concern. My concern here is that if I was just fed positional data of triangles making up a model, I would have to decide the normal based on that positional data but it also must be facing away from the model. which means some how I must know that the cross product will leave me with a normal that is facing away or toward my model in the first place.

Comment: normally triangles are only drawn one way. Sounds like the triangles on the back are being drawn in the wrong vertex order. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip

Comment: Wow this comment is a game changer. Does modeling software like blender obeys this convention? If it does then perhaps maybe I don't need to worry about it after all. I just need to be careful when generating my own I follow this convention.

Comment: Usually modeling software export in indices and I was wondering if the order of the indices will be in the manner describe above. The above describes triangle strips rather than having indices so I was wondering if it will be exported in the right order so that if I do the dot products it should work and have the face away from he model.