# Three.js, Calculating the transformation matrix between two BufferGeometry position state

Tags: matrix, three.js, geometry, position, transform

I'm working on a AR project, where an objects detection AI return the vertices of the detected object.

On the scene I have the detected object as the parent mesh with a `BufferGeometry` and the `position attributes` updated from the AI output, I need to calculate its transformation matrix when the vertices change and apply those transformation to its children.

How can I calculate the transformation matrix (Translation, Scaling, Rotation) from one "detection (position vertices)" to another.

Here is a simplified illustration of my problem, where the blue plane is the detected object and the red one its child, I need to calculate the blue plane transformation from its previous position apply them to red one so they can move together :

https://jsfiddle.net/uv76tj89/1/

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you just change `parent.rotation`, instead of assigning new vertices? The way you're re-assigning vertex positions doesn't really generate a transformation matrix.

Comment: It's a kind of AR, I get the vertices from an object detection AI, so I have to deal with geometry position and vertices ... My bad, I'll edit my question for more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the child geometry is going to be half as big as the parent geometry, just apply `child.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);` and then assign the exact same vertex positions as the parent on update with:

```js
parentGeometry.getAttribute('position').array = parentPositions[posIndex];
parentGeometry.getAttribute('position').needsUpdate = true;
childGeometry.getAttribute('position').array = parentPositions[posIndex];
childGeometry.getAttribute('position').needsUpdate = true;
```

the Three.js engine will apply the 1/2 scale and +5 to the z axis to the child vertices, so you don't have to worry about manually making these adjusments. See the demo below.

(Notice I created `Float32Array`s within `parentPositions[]` as an optimization so you don't have to make a new array and a new `BufferAttribute` each time you update them. It's not a noticeable performance boost with just 4 vertices, but it does help when you have 1000's of vertices).

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( window.innerWidth / - 2, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerHeight / - 2, 1, 1000 );
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias : true});
renderer.setClearColor(0x444444);
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
camera.position.z = 100;
new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

/* Helpers */
// Grid helper
var width = 100;
var height = 100;
var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(width * 2, 10, 0x999999, 0x000000);
gridHelper.position.y = -height / 2;
scene.add(gridHelper)
// Axes helper
scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(50));

/* parent Mesh */
var parentGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(width, height);
var parentMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:  0x209ad6} );
var parent = new THREE.Mesh( parentGeometry, parentMaterial );
scene.add(parent);


/* Child mesh */
var childGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(width, height);
var childMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color:  0xFF0000} );
var child = new THREE.Mesh( childGeometry, childMaterial );
parent.add(child);

// Apply desired transformations to the child Mesh
child.position.z = 5;
child.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);

/* Parent positions */
// Make all position arrays Float32Array
// so we don't have to create a new one each frame.
var parentPositions = [
 //Reference point
  new Float32Array([
    -50, 50, 0,
    50, 50, 0,
    -50, -50, 0,
    50, -50, 0
  ]),
  //Variations
 new Float32Array([
     -50, 50, 50,
      50, 50, 50,
      -50, -50, -50,
      50, -50, -50
 ]),
  new Float32Array([
     -75, 75, -25,
      75, 75, -25,
      -75, -75, 25,
      75, -75, 25
 ]),
  new Float32Array([
     0, 75, -25,
      75, 0, -25,
      -75, 0, 25,
      0, -75, 25,  
 ]),
  //... random positions
];

var lastTime = 0;
var posIndex = 0;

function render(currentTime) {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
  
  // Update position attributes
  // Instead of making a new attribute on each update
   if (currentTime >= lastTime + 1000)  {
     parentGeometry.getAttribute('position').array = parentPositions[posIndex];
     parentGeometry.getAttribute('position').needsUpdate = true;
     childGeometry.getAttribute('position').array = parentPositions[posIndex];
     childGeometry.getAttribute('position').needsUpdate = true;

     lastTime = currentTime;
     posIndex = posIndex === 3 ? 0 : posIndex + 1;
  }

  
  

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
render()
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r110/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure why you originally made the child a `PlaneGeometry`, but I had to change it to match the parent `PlaneBufferGeometry`.

#### Edit:

I guess I'm just now starting to understand what your problem is, and you'd need to calculate the vector that's perpendicular to your plane face. You can pick any three out of the four vertices to do this:
[image]

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350792/calculate-normal-of-a-single-triangle-in-3d-space) to figure out which point the triangle is pointing towards, and then you can make the `child` point in that direction with [`child.lookAt(x, y, z);`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt)

You can read [this article](http://www.leadinglesson.com/problem-on-finding-a-vector-perpendicular-to-a-triangle) for a little more in-depth explanation on how to get that perpendicular.

Comment: I'm sorry again, cause my exemple confused you, the child geometry can be anything from a square to cercle to a loaded gltf. Just applying the the same position vertices as the parent want do it. I really need some way to compute the parent transformation or somehow transform its child relatively.
Thanks for the `BufferAttribute` tip and seriously, I appreciate the help.
(Gave an up vote, want show up till I get some more reputation).

Comment: @localdev I see... I just added an edit at the bottom of my answer to point you in the right direction.